# Deleting similar lines?

Tags: shell, awk, diff

I have been using this to delete lines from first file that are in second file (difference).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++}FNR!=NR && !a[$0]{print}' file2.txt file1.txt >output.txt
```

This works perfecty for lines that are exactly the same, also it work fast with files with millions of lines.
Now, I have stumble upon situation where I have lines that are similar to lines in first file, but not exactly the same, some lines have 8-9 characters appended at the begining, but they are the same up to the end of a line, like this:

file1

```
8952aa182685763d30758c730de536a9907f96e7
5e46468f50df8e410b0372dc8a550c0cec33d8bc
11111111-954f94fa00c220c40a49b37816c9146
5dd0a2058734e2c3e039f3a814fc86789474c65e
2222222-s54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7a
```

file2

```
5e46468f50df8e410b0372dc8a550c0cec33d8bc
954f94fa00c220c40a49b37816c9146
s54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7a
```

Wanted result:

```
8952aa182685763d30758c730de536a9907f96e7
5dd0a2058734e2c3e039f3a814fc86789474c65e
```

I tried to find a solution but so far I didn't, if you have a solution that was already solved share a link, thanks in advance.

Comment: what if file2 pattern is in middle or beginning (eg. file2 has `x` and file1 has `xy` or `wxy` rather than `yx`) ? If you don't care where on the  line, you can just use `grep -vf file2 file1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are really after is the following:

```
$ awk -F'-' '(FNR==NR){a[$NF]; next}!($NF in a)' file2 file1
```

This splits each line in fields separated by a `-`. So for file1, the `$NF` value is given by

```
8952aa182685763d30758c730de536a9907f96e7 -> 8952aa182685763d30758c730de536a9907f96e7
5e46468f50df8e410b0372dc8a550c0cec33d8bc -> 5e46468f50df8e410b0372dc8a550c0cec33d8bc
11111111-954f94fa00c220c40a49b37816c9146 -> 954f94fa00c220c40a49b37816c9146
5dd0a2058734e2c3e039f3a814fc86789474c65e -> 5dd0a2058734e2c3e039f3a814fc86789474c65e
2222222-s54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7a -> s54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7a
```

This is exactly the string which you want to match from `file2` which is also referenced with `$NF` as it contains a single field. This, however, could be problematic if there are naturally more hyphens in the lines.

This **might** be better than the grep solution as the grep solution might remove false positives. Imagine lines in file1 that look like:

```
xxs54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7axxxxxx
yyys54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7ayyyyy
zzzzs54b2c1d6176b0aae91d85545670aa7azzzz
```

All these will be removed. In the above case, this is not going to be the case.

You could also address the problem differently by stating

> Don't show the lines of file1 where the lines of file2 match the end of the corresponding line in line1.

This can be solved with awk in the following way:

```
$ awk '(FNR==NR){a[$0]; next}
       {for(str in a) if (index($0,str)+length(str)-1==length($0)) print }' file2 file1
```

We could have used `match` instead of `index`, but `match` will match ERE patterns and if `str` contains any special ERE patterns, it will miss its purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find the lines in `file1` without a partial match in `file2` is:

```
grep -v -f file2 file1
```

Where you use the inverted match of those line listed in `file2` against the lines in `file1` resulting in:

```
8952aa182685763d30758c730de536a9907f96e7
5dd0a2058734e2c3e039f3a814fc86789474c65e
```

Comment: Be aware that this might also delete false positives, but depends on the problem at hand. In the above command, if `file2` contains a line stating `23`, all lines which have the sequence `23` will be removed.

Comment: Also look out for empty lines in `file2`, wiping out everything.